# Maven plugin to extract hardcoded dependencies/plugins versions into properties

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

does anyone know if there is a maven plugin to extract **hardcoded** dependencies/plugins **versions** into **properties**?

For example:

**pom.xml**:

```
...
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

will become something like:

**pom.xml**:

```
...
<properties>
    <log4j.version>1.2.14</log4j.version>
    <maven-release-plugin.version>2.5.3</maven-release-plugin.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-release-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
...
```

?

Comment: Unfortunately there is not such a plugin...the plugin I know is the person in front of the keyboard ;-)

Comment: Apart from that plugins should be defined by using pluginManagement in a parent/corporate pom...

Comment: I agree (having plugins or deps managed by parent pom |if any]). But still, that doen't change my original query. It sounds like a good new opensource mission for me then ! :)